# Child partial not injecting styles into its parent blade layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I have one partial child view that requires some custom js and styles. This child is the only view in the entire application that uses it. It's complex and so the JS was broken off into its own file.

I have tried to 'inject' the script and style into the parent layout [according to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#extending-a-layout) and it doesn't seem to be working. I have tired a combination of `@parent` and `@@parent` in the sections. I have tried changing the main layouts, `@yield('scripts')` `@yield('styles')` to `@section('scripts')@show`.

**What am I missing? Is this even possible?**

**main.blade.php**  (Shortened For Brevity)

```
<head>
    @include('apps.includes.styles')

    @yield('styles')//a place for custom style
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')

@include('apps.includes.scripts')
@yield('scripts') //a place for custom scripts
</body>
```

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('styles')@endsection
@section('scripts')@endsection
@section('content')
    <div>
      @include('partials._toolbar')
    </div>
@endsection
```

**_toolbar.blade.php**

```
@section('styles')
    @parent
    <script src="{{asset('assets/css/mystyle.css')}}"></script>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    @parent
    <script src="{{asset('assets/js/myjs.js')}}"></script>
@endsection

<section>
// my toolbar html code
</section>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible. You can fill sections only by extending a layout, not by including it. Instead, use a **stack** for your styles:

**toolbar.blade.php**

```
@push('styles')
    <script src="{{asset('assets/css/mystyle.css')}}"></script>
@endpush
```

**main.blade.php**

```
<head>
    @include('apps.includes.styles')

    @stack('styles')
</head>
```

You can read more about stacks in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#stacks).

Comment: Then what is the `@parent `used for?

Comment: It is used to _extend_ the content of a section. But only when _extending_ a layout with `@extends('parent.layout')`. It is a different perspective compared to an _include_. Extending is a bottom-up process, whereas an include happens top-down.

Comment: The `@push` worked. I have to wait 8 more minutes to accept the answer. I'll be back later to do that.